# Swift async let Task throws Cancellation Exception if not Awaited

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, concurrency

I am new to Swift Concurrency and trying to understand Task -> ChildTask relationship.

I created here two Tasks

- Parent Task :

  - (1)Calls the test() method in Actor from MainThread.
  - (3.2)The Actor calls the test() method in Background Thread...
  - (2)then returns the control to the parent task  on the MainThread
- Child Task:

  - (3)Runs in MainThread

```
class MyViewController: ViewController {
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        print("1 \(Thread.current.isMainThread)")
        Task {
            
            async let _ = ViewModel().test()        // Throws 3.3 CancellationError()
            // await ViewModel().test()             // Does not cancel task and works fine
            
            
            print("2 \(Thread.current.isMainThread)")
            Task {
                do {
                    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.5)
                    print("4.1 \(Thread.current.isMainThread)")
                } catch {
                    print("4.2 \(Thread.current.isMainThread)")
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    actor ViewModel {
        func test() async {
            print("3.1 \(Thread.current.isMainThread)")
            
            do {
                print("3.2 \(Thread.current.isMainThread)")
                let images = try await downloadImage()
            } catch {
                print("3.3 \(error)")
            }
        }
        
        func downloadImage() async throws -> UIImage {
            try Task.checkCancellation()
            await Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1) // 1seconds
            return UIImage()
        }
    }
}
```

```
async let _ = ViewModel().test()        // Throws 3.3 CancellationError()
// await ViewModel().test()
1 true
2 true
3.1 false
3.2 false
3.3 CancellationError()
4.1 true
```

```
// async let _ = ViewModel().test()        
await ViewModel().test()             // Does not cancel task and works 
1 true
3.1 false
3.2 false 
2 true 
4.1 true
```

*My Question here is, why is the Task is cancelled when I dont wait for the* **async_let test() method**

Comment: Why are you using `Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)`? That method should be unavailable from async contexts. Did you mean `Task.sleep` instead?

Comment: Same result, even if I use Task.sleep(nanosecond:) @Sweeper

Comment: Umm, I didn't say that will fix it... Just that you should not use `Thread.sleep` in async contexts. You should also not use `Thread.current` either.

Comment: You seem to think the inner `Task { ... }` as a "child task" of the outer one? That is not true. Even if that is the case, why would you *not* expect a `CancellationError`? By the time the task finishes (i.e. after 0.5 seconds), `ViewModel().test()` will not have finished, so it got cancelled.

Comment: Looks like though, even increasing the inner task sleep, didn't help. So I assure that the parent task won't wait for the child tasks to finish.

Comment: And because of that, the async let gets deInitialized and safe to assume to get cancelled automatically. I think

Comment: Thank you @Sweeper. I still will also do some more test on this.

Comment: After Testing multiple times,,, the reason it throws Cancellation is, if I dont await for the async_let_x variable, it is deallocated and cancelled.

Comment: Correct, it is cancelled because its parent task ended. See also my answer.

Comment: A minor terminology clarification: The title of this question refers to a cancellation “exception”. It actually throws an *error* (namely, a [`CancellationError`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cancellationerror)) not an *exception.* Errors and exceptions are very different things. Exceptions are serious faults (generally generated by the OS as a result of some unrecoverable problem, crashing the app), whereas errors are generally gracefully caught and handled within the app, part of standard flow control in our apps. We understood what you meant, but FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `Thread.current` or `Thread.sleep` in `async` contexts. This will be an error in Swift 6. Let's remove those and just consider this code:

```
Task {
    async let _ = ViewModel().test()
    Task {
        do {
            try await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(500))
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

```
actor ViewModel {
    func test() async {
        do {
            let images = try await downloadImage()
            print("Finished!")
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func downloadImage() async throws -> UIImage {
        try Task.checkCancellation()
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
        return UIImage()
    }
}
```

You seem to think that the task that waits for 0.5 seconds is a "child" of the task that runs `ViewModel().test()`. This is not true. By using `Task { ... }`, you start a *top level task* that is not a child of anything. And you don't `await` this task, so all the outer `Task` does, is start the task of `ViewModel().test()`, start another top level task (doesn't wait for it), and ends.

To actually wait for the top-level task, you can do:

```
await Task {
    ...
}.value
```

But if all you want is to wait for some time, you don't need a top-level task at all.Just directly write:

```
do {
    try await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(500))
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Now the task of "`Task.sleep`" is a child task of the single top level task you created. I'll assume you made the above change from now on.

Unlike `await` which actually waits, `async let` runs in parallel with the code around it. See [this section](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency/#Calling-Asynchronous-Functions-in-Parallel) in the Swift guide for an example. No one is waiting for it to complete if you don't `await` the variable created by `let` (which you didn't even a give a name to) at some point.

```
async let x = someAsyncThing()
anotherThing() // this line will not wait for someAsyncThing to finish
let result = await x // now we wait
```

So no one waits for `ViewModel().test()` to complete. You only wait for 0.5 seconds after launching `ViewModel().test()` in parallel, and that's not enough time for `ViewModel().test()` to finish. After 0.5 seconds, the top level task ends, the task running `ViewModel().test()` gets cancelled because it is a child task of the top level task. That explains the `CancellationError`.

Answer (score 1):

You ask:

> My Question here is, why is the Task is cancelled when I dont wait for the async_let test() method

See [SE-0317 - async let - implicit async let awaiting](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0317-async-let.md#implicit-async-let-awaiting), which says that if you fail to `await`, that it will be “implicitly cancelled and awaited”.

Consider:

```swift
func go() async { 
    async let f = foo()
    print("\(#function) nevermind...")
    // implicitly: cancels f
    // implicitly: await f
}

func foo() async throws {
    do {
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(1))
        print("\(#function) done")              // because async let will implicitly cancel this, and because `Task.sleep` detects cancellation and throws `CancellationError`, we won’t get here
    } catch {
        print("\(#function) error \(error)")    // when async let is implicitly canceled, `CancellationError` will be caught here
        throw error                             // but rethrown here
    }
}
```

If you run this, because [`Task.sleep`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/sleep(for:tolerance:clock:)) is non-blocking and handles cancelation, as soon as `f` falls out of scope, `foo` is immediately canceled. It is also awaited, but because cancelation is handled immediately, that is hard to observe.

So, let us consider this example:

```swift
func go() async { 
    async let f = foo()
    async let b = bar()
    print("\(#function) nevermind...")
    // implicitly: cancels f
    // implicitly: cancels b
    // implicitly: await f
    // implicitly: await b
}

func foo() async throws {…}                     // same as above

func bar() async throws {
    do {
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)        // never Thread.sleep, but for illustrative purposes, we want something that does not directly respond to cancellation 
        try Task.checkCancellation()            // we'll manually check for cancelation when `Thread.sleep` is done
        print("\(#function) done")              // because async let is implicitly canceled and `checkCancellation` will detect that, we won’t get here
    } catch {
        print("\(#function) error \(error)")    // we will catch `CancellationError` here
        throw error                             // and rethrow it here
    }
}
```

Now, in this case, you will again see this implicitly cancel and await both `foo` and `bar`. But because `bar` is poorly written and uses a blocking `Thread.sleep` (i.e., the cancelation is not immediately handled, but rather only detected after `Thread.sleep` finishes and we manually `checkCancellation`), the `go` function will `await` the completion of `bar`.

But if we change `bar` to proactively respond to cancelation, i.e., to use `Task.sleep` instead (like `foo`), then both are now quickly canceled and awaited.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sweeper told, The parent task won't wait for the child task to complete, they only share the Task's Context (whether it is to be cancelled or the thread it was started from)

I added some `defer {logs}` to the task, and found that the parent task is deallocated `prints 5.x` before the cancellation. and so the async_let_task is also cancelled...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        print("1 ")
        Task {
            async let x = ViewModel().test()        // Throws 3.3 CancellationError()
            // await ViewModel().test()             // Does not cancel task and works fine
            
            print("2 ")
            Task {
                do {
                    print("4.0 ")
                    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
                    print("4.1 ")
                } catch {
                    print("4.2 ")
                    print(error)
                }
                
                defer {
                    print("4.X")
                }
            }
            
            defer {
                print("5.X")
            }
        }
    }
    
    actor ViewModel {
        func test() async {
            print("3.1 ")
            
            do {
                let images = try await downloadImage()
                print("3.2 ")
            } catch {
                print("3.3 \(error)")
            }
            
            defer {
                print("3.X")
            }
        }
        
        func downloadImage() async throws -> UIImage {
            try Task.checkCancellation()
            await Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1) // 1seconds
            return UIImage()
        }
    }
}
```

```
1 
2 
5.X
3.1 
4.0 
3.3 CancellationError()
3.X
4.1 
4.X
```